# Domain and range of $y=f(7)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My answer:

The only real number in the x-coordinate is $7$. Then, Domain ={7}

Every real number in the y-coordinate is paired with $7$. Then, Range $=\mathbb{R}$

But Wolframalpha answer is: Domain $=\mathbb{R}$, and Range =$\varnothing$

Please, could you help me to understand? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $y=f(x)=7$ ?

Comment: @ Peter: No. I mean x has always the constant value 7.

Comment: Then, we only have a relation $x=7$. This is not a function from $x$. We could say $x=f(y)=7$, but this is a function from $y$.

Comment: Domain and range of what? If $f$ is any given function, then $y = f(7)$ is just an equation, not something that has a domain or range.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer: This is what I thought. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say $$y=f\left( 7 \right) =c_{ 0 }$$ for all **R**  it always will be $c_{ 0 }$ so the domain of function is **R**

But we can't say anything about range of the function because we don't know what the fucntion exactly is (${ c }_{ 0 }$- can be every thing).So I think therefore Wolframalpha asnwered Range $=\varnothing $